# Using parse in Xamarin Forms PCL throws errors

Tags: dll, parse-platform, xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I've setup a Xamarin.Forms project with a PCL, a project for Android and a project for iOS.
On the main project I've installed the Parse NuGet:
[image: NuGet]

I then added the Parse.dll and Parse.NetFx45.dll to the PCL:
[image: Added DLLs]

(which I downloaded from https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads and got it from the Xamarin SDK)

And finally on the Android project I've added the Parse.Android.dll and on the iOS project I've added the Parse.iOS.dll
When I now try to run this on Android I will get the following error:

```
07-29 16:34:30.274 I/MonoDroid(12848): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
07-29 16:34:30.279 I/MonoDroid(12848): System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Parse.ParseClient ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
07-29 16:34:30.279 I/MonoDroid(12848):   at Parse.ParseClient..cctor () [0x0008e] in <filename unknown>:0 
07-29 16:34:30.279 I/MonoDroid(12848):   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
07-29 16:34:30.279 I/MonoDroid(12848): at Begijn.App..ctor () [0x00008] in c:\Users\yenthe.vanginneken\Desktop\Begijn\Begijn\Forms_Example\App.cs:19
07-29 16:34:30.279 I/MonoDroid(12848): at Begijn.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x000dc] in c:\Users\yenthe.vanginneken\Desktop\Begijn\Begijn\Droid\MainActivity.cs:77
07-29 16:34:30.279 I/MonoDroid(12848): at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/1879/5f55a9ef/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-21/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:2707
07-29 16:34:30.279 I/MonoDroid(12848): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.a9794397-c74a-443b-b29b-77d845a6f0d6 (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00043>
```

The same issues happen on iOS too.
So, what am I missing or what am I doing wrong? :s
I've initialized Parse in the App.cs too.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but why are you manually adding the .dll files to the projects after you install the nuget package?

Comment: Because I thought that if the .dll files where there for the specific platform that I could get things working because it could access anything it needed.

Answer (score 2):

Like Matt said, you need an abstraction to surface Parse's functionality in a PCL.

I have a [sample TodoParse app](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/TodoParse) that does just that:

- In the PCL I created an [`IParseStorage` interface](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/TodoParse/TodoParse/Data/IParseStorage.cs)
- In each of the platform projects, there is a [`ParseStorage`](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/TodoParse/TodoParse.iOS/ParseStorage.cs) class that implements it

Refer to the [DependencyService docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) for details on how that works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is that all my data syncing is written inside the PCL and nothing is programmed in either the iOS or Android version. If I understand this correctly I can't use your method than?

Comment: What "data syncing" code is written inside the PCL, if you cannot access Parse inside the PCL? If you want to access Parse, you will *have* to put some code in iOS and Android projects (or switch from PCL to Shared Project for the Xamarin.Forms app)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you must then reimplement the ParseStorage for each platform, when the code for such would be exactly the same?  Also it seems that you must do a fairly significant amount of mapping between ParseObject and your PCL models.  I think it's a shame that Parse baked into their classes platform specific behaviours (such as local user cache) because it's my guess that's why there isn't a PCL library, even with so many similar questions on SO, the Tamarin Forms, and the Parse groups

Comment: @Conceptdev I've placed the sync page that is now in my PCL online here: https://github.com/Yenthe666/Notes/blob/master/SyncDataPage.xaml.cs could you have a look at this and what would be the best way to fix this? I've been trying at this for days without any succes.. (Sorry for the late reply I was on holiday too)

Answer (score 1):

The Parse NuGet package version 1.5.3 does not contain any PCL assemblies so I suspect that is the problem. It contains assemblies for:

- Android
- MonoTouch (iOS Classic)
- Xamarin.iOS (iOS Unified)
- NET 4.5
- Windows 8
- Windows Phone Silverlight 8
- Windows Phone for Applications 8.1

The .NET 4.5 Parse assemblies may well be using APIs that are not supported on iOS nor Android.

You would need to create an interface/abstraction in your PCL and have that implemented in your iOS and Android project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matt! Is it possible to create an interface/abstraction that works from the PCL and does not need anything implemented in the Android or iOS project? All my Parse code is only in the PCL.

Comment: You will need some code in the Android and iOS project since the Parse NuGet package only provides assemblies for those platforms. The code in the Android and iOS project would need to call the parse API. Unless Parse offer a PCL assembly you cannot call the Parse API directly in the PCL project.

Comment: Alright so I should remove my Parse code from the PCL and add code for Android to Android and for iOS to iOS? So there is no more syncing done on the XF PCL?

Comment: Yes move the code that uses the Parse API out of the PCL. So by syncing I am assuming you are refering to using Parse then yes you would not do that directly in the PCL. If the Parse API is the same for both iOS and Android you may be able to share the code between Android and iOS with a linked file instead of duplicating it in both projects.

Comment: my code looks like this: https://github.com/Yenthe666/Notes/blob/master/SyncDataPage.xaml.cs what would be the best way to make this work on both iOS and Android? I tried quite some things but nothing with succes. Could I add a new project with this code that I could reference somehow or? Any clue's/tips are welcome.